# Why is my Fullcalendar clientEvent firing only once when triggered by a jquery click event

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I am using Fullcalendar v3 clientEvent. I call it from within a Jquery click event call on a table row. When clicked the table row (representing the Calendar event record etc) with a unique id it fires the event and the object for the events is populated according to the calendar event id/record. The event info is returned. If I click on a second row in table the Jquery is again fired to redo the request for the next calendar event record and info. The action breaks at the point where the clientEvent is to return the event info..

On each Jquery click the new record number in variable rcd is populated and alerted;

My calendar listview (with events)

[Image of calendar listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETIOb.png)

My Calendar (with events)

```
$('#calendar1').fullCalendar({
   header: {
    left: 'title',
    center: '',
    right: ''
   },

   selectable: true,
   selectHelper: true,
   defaultView: 'listDay',

   events: 'list.php',
   eventColor:"#FF0000",

  });
```

My jquery event

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 

  //listen for event custom clicks 
    $("tr").click(function(e) 
    {
      var rcd = this.id;
     alert(rcd);
      var eobj = $('#calendar1').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(evts)
        {
            if(evts.record == rcd )
            {
            return true;    
            }           
            else 
            {   
            return false;
            }
        }); 
  });

});

alert(eobj.length);

var eventsrec = eobj[0].record;
alert(eventsrec);
```

I have tried searching for a solution for why only the first click event is returning the Calendar event record and not any other. I have even tried to remove the event, remove the Source, re adding the source, re rendering the events in the calendar. Still the same. Second request onward is not returning any calendar event record info. I believe somehow the event object named eobj needs to be reset or cleared. Struggling to get this to work every time I click the table row.

Found the following the Console error:

> TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function jquery.js jQuery 3
>    dispatch handle

Why would Jquery allow the first call and then not the res

Comment: Found the following the Console errors.
TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function
jquery.js 
    jQuery 3
        <anonymous>
        dispatch
        handle

Why would Jquery allow the first call and then not the rest.

Comment: Anyway, to be clear, you are saying this  " $(...).fullCalendar is not a function" error only occurs the **second** time you click on a row, is that right? Because that doesn't make any sense....

Comment: Can you make a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please, preferably as a live demo so we can actually see the issue occurring? You can use this JSFiddle as a starting point, if you like: http://jsfiddle.net/9a86h74m/

Comment: Hey ADyson. It sure ain't making any sense to me as well. The first row click works fine and returns the event detail. As soon as I click the second row or even the same again the process steps up to the point where the alert(rcd) pops up with the record number and then nothing returns further. That is when the consol error is generated. Will try and reproduce the situation so that you may check it out. Thanx.

Comment: Hey, ADyson. I believe I may have found the cause of the problem. The table row click event dynamically loads a new page in a div. Once this happends the origenal page looses focus. When the div is closed to focus is returned to the calender page. The jquery click event does not live inside the calendar defined class. So calling the calendar event from outside the calendar class with the clientEvent function is unable for some reason to retrieve the instance of the origenal events. This causing the fullcalendar function not to be referenced with retuning value. Giving the TypeError.. Thanx.